# Sending Base64 String To C# MVC Api Got Error

Tags: c#, json, rest, asp.net-mvc-4, base64

I convert a []byte to a base 64 string with this line

```
 filebase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(attachmentcontetn.Content);
```

and i put the filebase64 in a json like this:

```
 "{'RequestId':'" + requestforminst.Id
                                                     + "','filebase64':'" + filebase64 + "'}"
```

and then i send it to a rest api with this method: jsoninput is InputParameter Of RestApi Which contains Base64 Data And Some Additional Data

```
  string webapiUrl = generalurl;
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            string logineusername = username;
            string logineduserpassword = password;

            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(logineusername, logineduserpassword);
            var result = client.UploadString(webapiUrl, "POST", "=" + jsoninput);
            return result;
```

and in the REST Api I Convert The Base 64 To []byte With this line:

```
Convert.FromBase64String(modeldata.filebase64)
```

but it gets error of :"Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string."
befor calling restapi i checked my base64 data and convert it to []byte and it works correct and in destenition server got the error

Answer (score 0):

You can't post a string at webapi, maybe you should define a class or modify the receive type as dynamic.

Comment: i post string to web api and it works good and i only have problem with base64

Comment: no it's not correct but other data of json like RequestId is right

Comment: the length of a base64 encoded string is always a multiple of 4. If it is not a multiple of 4, then = characters are appended until it is.

Comment: you had better define a class to post and receive it. if you want use the string, please check the symbol like '+', '/', '='.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode to encode your base64 string before post